# where a "." is in my string make a new line after the "." and do the same to all the String

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to organize a string which is saved inside a Vector using regex, for that I need to make a new line where "." is seen in the string object, but in the other hand there has to be a space after the "." (\s) since we need to make sure that its the end of a sentence.
I'm having trouble  writing the method to reorganize my string using the algorithm above.

Comment: Code is better than English <3

Comment: Show the code you already have. Provide example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split on the index after `.` only if it is followed by a `\s` you can use positive look-behind: `(?<=\\.)\\s+`

Explanation of each item in the regular expression:

```
NODE       EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=       look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------
    \.         '.'
--------------------------------------------------------
  )          end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------
  \s+        whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
             more times (matching the most amount
             possible))
```

Here's a demo:

```java
String input = "Lorem ipsum. Dolor sit. Amet.";

for (String sentence : input.split("(?<=\\.)\\s+"))
    System.out.println("\"" + sentence + "\"");
```

Output:

```
"Lorem ipsum."
"Dolor sit."
"Amet."
```

Comment: but the "."s are missing

Comment: Right. I changed the rexep. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this (?):

```
string.replaceAll("\\. ", String.format("%n"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need this regex for `split`:

```
String input = "This is a sentence. Foo bar. Baz xyz. Last one.";
String[] tok = input.split( "(?<=\\.)\\s+" );
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT4oA4/1)

#### output:

```
This is a sentence.
Foo bar.
Baz xyz.
Last one.
```

Though just keep in mind that it will also split `Mr. Smith is a nice man`.

Comment: well you are right...any solution crosses your mind to prevent that?

Comment: Actually there is no foolproof way to avoid these situations since there are too many edge cases like that. One can maintain a whitelist words but that  will also be not 100% accurate.